# How to deal with timestamp string which contain plus(+) operator as well

Tags: java, postgresql

When I extract commit timestamp from postgres, I get value like "2014-02-27 16:41:51.863092+01" in string format. In java, when I try to convert this  string using

```
Timestamp.valueOf("2014-02-27 16:41:51.863092+01")
```

I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "863092+01"
```

What is the meaning of value after plus(+) operator and how can I convert to timestamp in java.

Comment: The `+01` should be the timezone

Comment: It is timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+01` represents the timezone. One way to parse it would be to do -

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-02-27 16:41:51.863092+01", formatter);
System.out.println(Timestamp.from(time.toInstant()));
```

[This link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) lists all the different formats supported by the Java date formatters.

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. It turned out that I am getting varying length of millisecond. I will try to find some workaround for that. Thanks :)

Comment: I have one more question. Does time zone really matter when we are converting this value to timestamp in java?

Comment: It depends on your use-case. If you need timezone information/your database is returning date with timezone, then yeah.